# Determinate unique values from oracle join?

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g

I need a way to avoid duplicate values from oracle join, I have this scenario.

The first table contain general information about a person.

```
+-----------+-------+-------------+
| ID        | Name  | Birtday_date|
+-----------+-------+-------------+
| 1         | Byron | 12/10/1998  |
| 2         | Peter | 01/11/1973  |
| 4         | Jose  | 05/02/2008  |
+-----------+-------+-------------+
```

The second table contain information about a telephone of the people in the first table.

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| ID    |ID_Person |CELL_TYPE | NUMBER   |
+-------+- --------+----------+----------+
| 1221  | 1        | 3        | 099141021|
| 2221  | 1        | 2        | 099091925|
| 3222  | 1        | 1        | 098041013|
| 4321  | 2        | 1        | 088043153|
| 4561  | 2        | 2        | 090044313|
| 5678  | 4        | 1        | 092049013|
| 8990  | 4        | 2        | 098090233|
+----- -+----------+----------+----------+
```

The Third table contain information about a email of the people in the first table.

```
+------+----------+----------+---------------+
| ID   |ID_Person |EMAIL_TYPE| Email         |
+------+- --------+----------+---------------+
| 221  | 1        | 1        |jdoe@aol.com   |
| 222  | 1        | 2        |jdoe1@aol.com  |
| 421  | 2        | 1        |xx12@yahoo.com |
| 451  | 2        | 2        |dsdsa@gmail.com|
| 578  | 4        | 1        |sasaw1@sdas.com|
| 899  | 4        | 2        |cvcvsd@wew.es  |
| 899  | 4        | 2        |cvsd@www.es    |
+------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

I was able to produce a result like this, you can check in this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8e326/1

```
+-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
| ID  | Name  | Birtday_date| CELL_TYPE|  NUMBER  |EMAIL_TYPE|EMAIL|
+-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 3        | 099141021|1         |jdoe@aol.com    |   
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 2        | 099091925|2         |jdoe1@aol.com   |  
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 1        | 099091925|          |                |  
| 2   | Peter | 01/11/1973  | 1        | 088043153|1         |xx12@yahoo.com  |
| 2   | Peter | 01/11/1973  | 2        | 090044313|2         |dsdsa@gmail.com |
| 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  | 1        | 092049013|1         |sasaw1@sdas.com |
| 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  | 2        | 098090233|2         |cvcvsd@wew.es   |
+-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
```

If you check the data in table Email for user with `ID_Person = 4` only present two of the three emails that have, the problem for this case is the person have more emails that cellphone numbers and only will present the same  number of the cellphone numbers.

The result i expected is something like this.

```
    +-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
    | ID  | Name  | Birtday_date| CELL_TYPE|  NUMBER  |EMAIL_TYPE|EMAIL|
    +-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
    | 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 3        | 099141021|1         |jdoe@aol.com    |   
    | 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 2        | 099091925|2         |jdoe1@aol.com   | 
    | 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 1        | 099091925|          |                | 
    | 2   | Peter | 01/11/1973  | 1        | 088043153|1         |xx12@yahoo.com  |
    | 2   | Peter | 01/11/1973  | 2        | 090044313|2         |dsdsa@gmail.com |
    | 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  | 1        | 092049013|1         |sasaw1@sdas.com |
    | 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  | 2        | 098090233|2         |cvcvsd@wew.es   |
    | 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  |          |          |2         |cvsd@www.es     |
    +-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
```

This is the way that i need to present the data.

Comment: can you also explain in other words what is your expected result? I can see Byron has 3 Phones and 2 emails. What do you want to see in the output in such case?

Comment: Hi, i added a example of the result what i expected

Comment: I got that, but that doesn explain why the result looks this way. Why is Jose in the result three times, why the others only two times? Why this combination of phone and emails in a row. Try to explain the logic behind the expected output.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained. Include everything needed, don't make us follow links. Especially not to your profile then somewhere again per "as i explained yesterday". Put the necessary explanation & code into your question as text.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the result that i expect, last time was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not understand why your query was so complex, thus, added the simple **full outer join** and it seems to be working:

```
select distinct p.id, p.name,
case when Lag(CELL) over(partition by p.id order by p.id,pe.id) = CELL then null else cell_type end as cell_type,
case when Lag(CELL) over(partition by p.id order by p.id,pe.id) = CELL then null else CELL end as CELL,
EMAIL_TYPE as EMAIL_TYPE, EMAIL as EMAIL
from person p full outer join phones pe on p.id = pe.id 
full outer join emails e
on p.id = e.id and pe.cell_type = e.email_type;
```

Comment: Thanks but the  problem i have is avoid duplicates values from the  join,  i updated the result that i expect, last time was wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, One question if I have the same scenario with the same expected result but the email type and cell_type don't have the sames values, How should make the join ??